# How to call a method from a different class (area of rectangle)

Tags: c++, class, methods

This is my first question on this website, I'm a relatively new programmer and I'm practicing c++. I made a code in c++ for finding the area and perimeter of a rectangle, where the user inputs the area and width themselves, and then the length is calculated using the formula along with the area and perimeter. I made two classes, one with the area and perimeter methods as calculations and the second class as another rectangle which I am trying to find the area and perimeter of. I am trying to use the same formula from the first class and call it into the second class so I don't need to write out the formula again, only the dimensions. Is this OOPS(object oriented programming)? Can anyone help me with this class and methods please?
Thank you,
Aditya
Image of the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zpJr.jpg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle {
  public:
  int length;
  int width;
  int area;
  int perimeter;
};

int main() {
  Rectangle calc1;
  cout << "Enter area= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.area;
  cout << "Enter width= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.width;
  calc1.length = (calc1.area / calc1.width);
  cout << "Length is " << calc1.length << endl;

  Rectangle calc2;

  calc2.perimeter = ((2 * calc1.length) + (2 * calc1.width));
  cout << "Perimeter is " << calc2.perimeter << endl;

  class Rectangle2 : public Rectangle {

  public:
  Rectangle2 calc3;
  cout << "Enter area= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.area;
  cout << "Enter width= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.width;
  calc1.length = (calc1.area / calc1.width);

  cout << "Area of rectangle 2 is" << calc3.T_area << endl;

}
```

Comment: Why not have just a single `Rectangle` class which knows how to calculate its area (e.g. `int Rectangle::CalculateArea ()`)?

Comment: I am very confused at what you are trying to do with the Rectangle2 class. Looks wrong for multiple reasons.

Comment: @drecherjm: the rectangle 2 class is the another rectangle in my code which is trying to follow the same formula in the rectangle 1 class, rectangle 2 prompts user for area and width as well and tries to find the length perimeter of the values given with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define class inside of function. Also if all members of a class are public then it is probably better to just use struct instate. Here is some example how it could look.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std; // this is bad

struct Rectangle {
  int length;
  int width;
  int area;

  int perimeter() { return ((2 * length) + (2 * width)); };
};

struct Rectangle2 : public Rectangle {

};

int main() {
  Rectangle calc1;
  cout << "Enter area= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.area;
  cout << "Enter width= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.width;
  calc1.length = (calc1.area / calc1.width);
  cout << "Length is " << calc1.length << endl;

  cout << "Perimeter is " << calc1.perimeter() << endl;

  Rectangle2 calc3;
  cout << "Enter area= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.area;
  cout << "Enter width= \n" << endl;
  cin >> calc1.width;
  calc1.length = (calc1.area / calc1.width);

  cout << "Area of rectangle 2 is" << calc3.area << endl;

}
```

Comment: Hi, I think my explanation was not clear enough. See, I'm trying to make it possible that I use the same formula from the class Rectangle, the first class, and have it so that when I input values for the area and width in the Rectangle 2 class it automatically knows I want to find the area of the second rectangle with the new dimensions. Makes sense? I'm not sure if this is how it works